# DSpace not listing Collections, java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: java, dspace

I have a DSpace instllation on a Mandravia Linux. I didn't install it, in fact I know very little about it.

It was working fine until recently when submissions started taking too long and collections weren't being displayed. This last error is shown as:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
=============================================
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    at     org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.preProcessCommunityHome(HandleServlet.java:486)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.communityHome(HandleServlet.java:438)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.doDSGet(HandleServlet.java:250)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.processRequest(DSpaceServlet.java:119)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.doGet(DSpaceServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentSubmissionsManager.getRecentSubmissions(RecentSubmissionsManager.java:76)
at org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentCommunitySubmissions.process(RecentCommunitySubmissions.java:48)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.preProcessCommunityHome(HandleServlet.java:480)
... 21 more




null
=============================================
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:417)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
at org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentSubmissionsManager.getRecentSubmissions(RecentSubmissionsManager.java:76)
at org.dspace.app.webui.components.RecentCommunitySubmissions.process(RecentCommunitySubmissions.java:48)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.preProcessCommunityHome(HandleServlet.java:480)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.communityHome(HandleServlet.java:438)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.HandleServlet.doDSGet(HandleServlet.java:250)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.processRequest(DSpaceServlet.java:119)
at org.dspace.app.webui.servlet.DSpaceServlet.doGet(DSpaceServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I've been thinking that a good solution would be to make a fresh install of DSpace, but I'm afraid that the problem is corrupted data, null values or something of the sort.

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the source, it appears that you have not set the `recent.submissions.count` property.

Relevant source code is [here](https://svn.duraspace.org/dspace/dspace/branches/dspace-1_5_x/dspace-jspui/dspace-jspui-api/src/main/java/org/dspace/app/webui/components/RecentSubmissionsManager.java).

Comment: Thank you Flavio. I am completely in the dark about this, how would you go about setting the `recent.submissions.count` property?

Comment: Flavio, just for the record. I could fix it setting the value you identified in the dspace.cfg file. THANKS!!!